# Event isReminderSet field is not functioning correctly

Tags: event

**Problem**

I have added the *IsReminderSet* field to the Lightning Component. All settings are correct in the activity settings as far as enabling notifications. However, when users save the event, the reminder is set to true in the component, but when it's committed the field is actually not set. Not sure whey this is the case, but can anyone give some insight on how to change the appearance of this field to false? Or explain what this kind of behavior is for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this field just indicates whether or not `ReminderDateTime` is set. Are you actually putting any value in this field?

Comment: Correct, but it's not actually set when it's saved. I'll update with saved record screenshot.

Comment: I don't think it's writable, and I don't think you answered my question on if `ReminderDateTime` gets set.

Comment: Sorry, Reminder Date Time is not getting set. Despite being selected in the picklist.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If you go to the event record after its committed, you can set the ReimderDateTime. It just wont get set from the Lightning Component.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this bug is a known issue and is in the Winter'19 release notes as a fix, however there is no notice on Salesforce's documentation for the feature informing the user that its busted and can't be used till Winter'19. Searching "How to Set up Event Reminders in Salesforce" produces the following article: [Set Up Lightning Experience Event Reminders](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=events_enable_reminders.htm&type=5)

But after much more research, the Reminder Set feature is broken and the initial values that are being set on Reminder Date/Time field (hidden field) are not being set and you can verify this with the following trigger used to debug the record:

```
    trigger EventTrigger on Event (before insert) {

//trigger used for debugging the default values an Event Record. 
    System.Debug(Trigger.new); 
     for(Event e : Trigger.New) {
        System.debug('e.Subject = '+ e.Subject);
         System.debug('e.ReminderDateTime = '+ e.ReminderDateTime);
         System.debug('e.IsReminderSet = '+ e.IsReminderSet);


    }   
}
```

My goal was to get the values of that field so that I could use them in a Process Builder, but since there is no value being passed to that field, despite the user selecting a value, I'm not sure how to proceed. If someone has a better answer or critique, please post/comment. Thanks,

If you want to use more fields just add e.[fieldname] from the [Event Object Reference on Salesforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Event.htm)